# (std::__cxx11::string) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>] cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl

C++ showing error with constructor overloading in templates

```
(std::__cxx11::string) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]cannot be overloaded
```

I am trying to overload a Template class constructor here.
Extended error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
dlist.h: In instantiation of class Sinwan::DList::DoublyLinkList<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >:
main.cpp:5:45:   required from here
dlist.h:62:13: error:Sinwan::DList::DoublyLinkList<T>::DoublyLinkList(std::__cxx11::string) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>] cannot be overloaded
             DoublyLinkList(std::string dummyData_)
             ^
dlist.h:52:13: error: with Sinwan::DList::DoublyLinkList<T>::DoublyLinkList(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
             DoublyLinkList(T dummyData_)
```

code inside my .h file:

```
DoublyLinkList(T dummyData_)
{
    node = new Node;//dummy node
    node->_next=NULL;
    node->_prev=NULL;
    node->_data=dummyData_;
    head=node;
    tail=node;
    _iteratorObj=begin();
}
DoublyLinkList(std::string dummyData_)
{
    node = new Node;//dummy node
    node->_next=NULL;
    node->_prev=NULL;
    node->_data=dummyData_;
    head=node;
    tail=node;
    _iteratorObj=begin();
}
```

Main.cpp:

`#include<iostream>`

`#include "dlist.h"`

`int main()`

`{`

`Sinwan::DList::DoublyLinkList<std::string>::Iterator it;`

`Sinwan::DList::DoublyLinkList<std::string> listObj("0");`

`}`

If I change std::string to int, it works fine. Can anybody help me to point out the prblm??

Comment: That could not be the complete and full error. Please copy-paste the full and complete error output, including possible informational notes. Then please mark where in the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the error(s) are, for example with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

We still don't have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but at least it's possible to *guess* about the problem.

Assuming that `T` is a class template argument, then if you have `DoublyLinkList<std::string>` then the type `T` will be `std::string`, and you will have *two* constructors taking `std::string` as argument. You can't have that, if you overload a function (constructor or other) it *must* have different signatures.

You should probably not have the constructor taking an explicit `std::string` argument.

Comment: Okay, then what can i do to initialise the node->data with "0" (string 0) when template is string type and node->data as 0 (int 0) when template type is int

Comment: @SinwanMohammed That will happen automatically by passing the correct argument to the constructor. If you have a list of `std::string` object, then you pass `std::string` arguments. If you have a list of `int` values, then you pass `int` values.

Comment: Thanks dude, that was helpfull